# excel vba sort RGB across all sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code for sorting in ascending / descending order across all sheets and I need some assistance to edit this code to sort using RGB colors

```
Sub SortAllSheets()
   Dim WS      As Worksheet
   ActiveSheet.Range("a1:f1").Select
   Selection.Copy
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   For Each WS In Worksheets
      WS.Columns("A:F").Sort Key1:=WS.Columns("B"), Order1:=xlDescending
   Next WS
   ActiveSheet.Range("G1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Question :**
How can I edit the code above to sort using RGB?

```
Value.Color = RGB(255, _199, 206) instead of normal asc /des order
```

Comment: Do you want to sort in the order of `RED`-`GREEN`-`BLUE`? Is this text color or fill color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a macro record of what you want - `filter by color`. Here is the code

```
Sub ColorSort()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range( _
        "D3:D9"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = _
        RGB(255, 0, 0)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

See if you can use this in your code and bring the required effect.

**More information:**

Here is how my spreadsheet looks before sort.

[image: Sample data]

Select the area that needs to be sorted using the `Sort by Color`

[image: Sort by Color - Dialog]

In the `Order` column of the Sort dialog, just select `RED`, then, the result will look like this.

[image: Sorted image]

Comment: thank you for your response Prasanna, im afraid this is not going to work already try that.

This will work on only one sheet the code im using above is for all my sheets in a specific workbook

Comment: @EnrikShaumann, That is why I gave you the result of the recorded macro above. Just to show you how the macro was recorded I wrote the **More information** section. Please customize the above code into your existing code. I'm sure there is a way here

Comment: my bad, been trying to edit this code but in vain, will keep you updated